# SVN: is it possible to get svn info for a given revision number of a branch

Tags: svn, branch, revision

Is it possible to get svn info for a branch for a specific revision number. For example if the latest working copy of a branch has revision number 56, can I get info for the same branch for revsion number 32.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two options available to get informatioon about past revisions:

- `svn log -r <rev number> <url>`: the commit message of a specified revision and url
- `svn info -r <rev number> <url>`: some technical information about a specified revision and url

An example: `svn log -r 5628 https://repo.exampl.org/prod/branches/info/conf/config`

It is all described in the help messages built into the svn command: `svn help` or `svn help info`...

Comment: @milosmns No, these commands offer information about a specific revision, not about a difference to another revision. For that you want to use the `svn diff` sub command. It is well documented.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are in a working copy, you can just do the following:

Get commit info:

```
svn log -c <rev number>
```

Get commit info with file list:

```
svn log -c <rev number> -v
```

Get full file diff:

```
svn diff -c <rev number>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes u can get the information for the what revision u want.

```
svn cat -r <rev number> path upto which file u want see the revisions
```

ex: svn cat -r 34 svn:///dmlrepo/trunk/1.txt