# Extracting SVN info of a branch from a older revision using CMake commands

Tags: svn, cmake

I have an issue something related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555944/svn-is-it-possible-to-get-svn-info-for-a-given-revision-number-of-a-branch) but more with CMake commands.

I am using find package in my project to get info about working copy revision which i need to display in my application.

```
# Load built-in SVN module
find_package(Subversion)

if(SUBVERSION_FOUND)
    # WC_INFO will define ${PROJECT_NAME}_WC_REVISION among others
    subversion_wc_info(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${PROJECT_NAME})

    set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_REVISION ${${PROJECT_NAME}_WC_REVISION})
endif()
```

**Issue:**

I created a branch from an older revision `(#300)` to fix some bug and switched the new branch to current working copy. But when i run `find_package(Subversion)` command on the newly created branch it gives me the same WC copy revision `#363`. I was expecting to get `#355` i.e. `${${PROJECT_NAME}_WC_REVISION}` working copy revision for the new branch should be `#355`. But i am getting `#363` for both the branches.

```
      Main
        |
   #300 |---branch
        |   |
        |   | 
        |   HEAD (committed changes at #355)
        |
        |
       HEAD
       #363
```

Am i missing something here? I thought `${${PROJECT_NAME}_WC_REVISION}` should give me HEAD revision of currently requested branch. How do i get the `svn HEAD info` for respective branches?

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem. Did you already deleted the CMakeCache.txt file and repeated the CMake run?

Comment: "But when i run `find_package(Subversion)` command on the newly created branch..." - you probably mean command `subversion_wc_info` which is intended to examine your project. The command `find_package(Subversion)` just locates `svn` executable, not a your project.

Comment: i feel stupid now. @vre it was the cache problem. It worked. thanks! I would mark your suggestion as an answer if you are willing to add it. Or else i will just answer my own question just to resolve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching branches in the `Subversion` repository you need to remove the `CMakeCache.txt` and rerun `CMake`.